# How to set predefined ordinal values for parallel coordinates in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I want to know how to set predefined ordinal values for parallel coordinates?

For example ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/yFXqj/)) if we remove the car with "blue" value, the D3 remove the blue label for us, but I want define my set of labels first (blue,red,green) and then D3 show blue label without connection (if I remove the blue car).

```
{"name": "AMC Concord DL 6", "weight (lb)":3265, "0-60 mph (s)": 18.2, "year": 79, "colour": "blue"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're setting the domain (i.e. all the possible colour values) like this:

```
y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
```

So, inherently, if `cars` doesn't contain a blue car, that value doesn't make it into the domain.

Since you're asking for the colour value to be there even if it's not in `cars`, I presume you're ok hard-coding the domain's values (because otherwise there's no way for "blue" to make it into the dataset/domain). So, to hard code, replace the `.domain()` call above with:

```
y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['blue', 'green', 'red'])
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucy55gq/).